# how to set highlightDuration in karate-config.js

Tags: karate

I have added below for highlight duration:

```
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'geckodriver', executable: 'executable', showDriverLog: true, highlightDuration: 1000 });
```

But actually element is being highlighted for 3000 ms (which is by default). What am i doing wrong?

Comment: actually it is a little unstable to be honest and designed only for when you are developing tests. do consider contributing code to make it better

Comment: sure, i will look into it if i get time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add `highlight: true` also.

```
karate.configure('driver', { type: 'geckodriver', executable: 'executable', showDriverLog: true, highlight: true, highlightDuration: 1000 });
```

Comment: @PeterSmith i added highlight: true as well, but it still highlighting the element for 3000 ms, Also it's unstable in terms of : it highlights another elements randomly